# returning the number of weeks and days

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the difference between two dates and the return the number of weeks and days as the output. I can get the number of weeks but I am struggling to take the decimal and then turn that into the day of the week. var EDC is a input from the user who is selecting the date from a calendar

```
var EDC = @D1125594448205.getTime();
var CurrentDate = new Date().getTime();
var DifferenceTime=(CurrentDate-EDC)/52;
DifferenceTime=(DifferenceTime/(1000*480*24));

return DifferenceTime;
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Will it always be the difference between current date or can the user pick both dates?

Answer (score 1):

DifferenceTime is the difference in milliseconds

Divide it by :

- the number of milliseconds in a second (1000)
- the number of seconds in a minute (60)
- the number of minutes in an hour (60)
- the number of hour in a day (24)

Will give you the number of day (truncate it and you get the number of days between your dates)

Divide this number of day by 7 (the number of days in a week) and you get the number of weeks

```
var DifferenceTime=(CurrentDate-EDC);
var nbDays = parseInt(DifferenceTime/ 1000 * (60 * 60 * 24));
var nbWeeks = parseInt(nbDays/7);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you meant?

```
var date1 = new Date(1125594448205).getTime();
var date2 = new Date().getTime();
var timeDiff = date2 - date1;
var difDays = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
var difWeeks = Math.floor(difDays / 7);
difDays = difDays - (difWeeks * 7);

alert(difWeeks + ' weeks ' + difDays + ' days');
```